# How to format one cell to match formatting of another (even if "other" changes later)?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

How can I do the Style equivalent of setting one cell equal to the style of another cell, even if the "other" cell style changes?

use Case:

I want all Row #2 of each sheet to look like (same style) as Sheet #1.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to achieve by non-scripting means. A partial solution would be to edit header/footer of your spreadsheet. It can be accessed by pressing **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>P</kbd>** and **editing custom fields**:

[image: 6]